# Create a simple proxy using Sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, proxy

can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong in my code.

I'm trying to create a simple HTTP proxy using sockets. I don't want to change the requests or responses in anyway, I just want to be able to relay requests/responses and record url requests from the browser.

This code isn't working properly, I realize there are several questions on SO relating to proxies and sockets using c# but I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The problem seems to be with my socket.receive, it's slow and takes a long time to complete. The browser waits for up to 10/20 seconds...

```
   int bytes = 0;
                do
                {
                    bytes = destServerSocket.Receive(responseBuffer);
                    client.Send(responseBuffer);
                }
                while (bytes > 0);
```

Sometimes I get a (SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host) when sending headers.

Sometimes I get a (SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine) when receiving a response

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace Proxy
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8888);
            server.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                Socket client = server.AcceptSocket();
                Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Program.Handle));
                t.Start(client);
                //Thread.Sleep(30);
            }
        }

        static void Handle(object clientSocket)
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)clientSocket;
            bool recveiveRequest = true;
            string EOL = "\r\n";

            string headers = "";
            string requestTempLine = "";
            List<string> requestLines = new List<string>();
            byte[] requestBuffer = new byte[1];
            byte[] responseBuffer = new byte[1024];

            Socket destServerSocket = null;

            requestLines.Clear();

            try
            {
                while (recveiveRequest)
                {
                    client.Receive(requestBuffer);
                    string fromByte = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(requestBuffer);
                    headers += fromByte;
                    requestTempLine += fromByte;

                    if (requestTempLine.EndsWith(EOL))
                    {
                        requestLines.Add(requestTempLine.Trim());
                        requestTempLine = "";
                    }

                    if (headers.EndsWith(EOL + EOL))
                    {
                        recveiveRequest = false;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Raw Request Received...");
                Console.WriteLine(headers);

                // TODO: record headers

                string remoteHost = requestLines[0].Split(' ')[1].Replace("http://", "").Split('/')[0];
                string requestFile = requestLines[0].Replace("http://", "").Replace(remoteHost, "");
                requestLines[0] = requestFile;

                headers = "";
                foreach (string line in requestLines)
                {
                    headers += line;
                    headers += EOL;
                }

                destServerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                destServerSocket.Connect(remoteHost, 80);
                destServerSocket.Send(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(headers));

                int bytes = 0;
                do
                {
                    bytes = destServerSocket.Receive(responseBuffer);
                    client.Send(responseBuffer);
                }
                while (bytes > 0);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error Occured: " + e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                destServerSocket.Close();
                client.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks, any help appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Try to profile your code to see performance problems. Try to increase size of your responseBuffer, improve header parsing code (it looks very inefficient to receive bytes one by one, convert them to string and add to string with += instead of StringBuilder and so on), also you can cache connections to remote server instead of recreating them on each request and so on. But before any changes it is always better to profile your code to see real problem.

Also i would recommend to read some examples of good code for proxies to learn some tricks. You current code looks very naive and inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Once you accept your socket, you should use async model and hook up an event listener for incoming data from both sides of the proxy (in client and out client). This will keep from blocking. You can then get rid of all the while loops.